In RHEL how does one set a default global DNS server using systemd NetworkManager instead of on a per nmcli connection basis?
In RHEL /etc/resolv.conf is dynamically generated/managed by systemd NetworkManager service by default nowadays and is generated by that same such service.
Using nmcli you can create DNS settings on a 'per connection' basis.
So how the heck does one add a GLOBAL default DNS server these days for the entire host/all nmcli connections?
systemd-resolved seems to be disabled in favor of NetworkManager and I would have to symlink /etc/resolve.conf to the file systemd-resolved manages /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
I imagine having two service dynamically generating the same file would cause problems

Did you check the Red Hat Enterprise Linux documentation? It has an entire chapter covering this.

Chapter 21. Manually configuring the /etc/resolv.conf file
By default, NetworkManager dynamically updates the /etc/resolv.conf
file with the DNS settings from active NetworkManager connection
profiles. However, you can disable this behavior and manually
configure DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf.

For any distribution using the NetworkManager it is also documented in the NetworkManager.conf(5).

MAIN SECTION
dns
  Set the DNS processing mode.

If the key is unspecified, default is used, unless /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf, /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, /lib/systemd/resolv.conf or
/usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf. In that case, systemd-resolved is chosen automatically.
default: NetworkManager will update /etc/resolv.conf to reflect the nameservers provided by currently active connections. The rc-manager setting (below) controls how this is done.

  – –

none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf. This implies rc-manager unmanaged.


printf "[main]\ndns=none\n" \
  | sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf
sudo systemctl reload NetworkManager

To keep keep your manually configured /etc/resolv.conf file safe even if this configuration gets altered causing NetworkManager to override this file, you could replace it with a symbolic link. You might as well remove the confusing comment section from the file.
sed '/^#/d' /etc/resolv.conf \
  | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured
sudo ln -s /etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured /etc/resolv.conf


I read that! But didn't see a way to set a default Nameserver thta would apply to all nmcli connections via Network Manager.  Does it require you to use systemd-resolved?  Guess that's something NetworkManager can't do for some reason?

I want both NetworkManager DNS servers and a backup default DNS server.
